# Using Excel to take a list and filter all of the data that doesn't meet the criteria

Tags: excel, filter

Desired result
[image]

I am trying to use the filter function but I'm having trouble remembering if this is even the correct formula I should be using. I want to take any items that have information in the D, G and J columns to create a new list.

```
=FILTER('Floor 5 Sweep'!A2, 'Floor 5 Sweep'!D2<>"","")
```

This semi works but leaves a lot of blanks in between as below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula which lets you choose which columns you wish to consider in a single function (`CHOOSECOLS`)

```
=FILTER(
    $A$2:$A$21,
    BYROW(
        CHOOSECOLS($A$2:$L$21, 4, 7, 10),
        LAMBDA(arr, OR(arr <> ""))
    )
)
```

[image]

Note that the column numbers in the `CHOOSECOLS` function can also be represented by an array of numbers generated by the `SEQUENCE` function. So if there is a pattern, it can easily be extended.  For example, the above formula would be equivalent to:

```
=FILTER(
    $A$2:$A$21,
    BYROW(
        CHOOSECOLS(
            $A$2:$L$21,
            SEQUENCE(3, , 4, 3)
        ),
        LAMBDA(arr, OR(arr <> ""))
    )
)
```

so if you wanted to include also columns `M` and `P` you would make just two changes in the `CHOOSECOLS` function as seen below:

```
=FILTER(
    $A$2:$A$21,
    BYROW(
        CHOOSECOLS(
            $A$2:$P$21,
            SEQUENCE(5, , 4, 3)
        ),
        LAMBDA(arr, OR(arr <> ""))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER(A2:A21,(D2:D21<>"")+(G2:G21<>"")+(J2:J21<>""))
```

Result:

[image]